# Find common attributes from nested array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is my schema:

```
  [{
    "attributes":[
        {
            "attrId":"123",
            "values":[
                    {"name": "asd"},
                    {"name": "bcc"}
                ]
        },
        {
            "attrId":"456",
            "values":[
                    {"name": "zzz"},
                    {"name": "bcc"}
                ]
        }
        ]
},

{
    "attributes":[
        {
            "attrId":"123",
            "values":[
                    {"name": "asd"},
                    {"name": "bcc"}
                ]
        },
        {
            "attrId":"456",
            "values":[
                    {"name": "kkk"},
                    {"name": "bcc"}
                ]
        }
        ]
}]
```

I want output as:

```
[{123:["asd","ccc"]}]
```

i.e to return `attrId` and values if all values match with all other documents,
I am thinking it to convert values into string like "asdbcc" so that it will be easy to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by null and make array of root objects and get count of total objects in root
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array that we have created in above stage
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root.attributes` array
- `$group` by `root.attributes.attrId` and `root.attributes.values` and get total count of grouped documents and values to get k(key) as `attrId` and v(value) as array of values from `values` object using `$map` and get first `totalCount` field
- `$match` expression using `$expr` check common document count and total root object document both are equal then return matching documents
- `$replaceRoot` to replace and object after converting from `$arraToObject` of `values` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      totalCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $unwind: "$root.attributes" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        attrId: "$root.attributes.attrId",
        values: "$root.attributes.values"
      },
      values: {
        $addToSet: {
          k: "$root.attributes.attrId",
          v: {
            $map: {
              input: "$root.attributes.values",
              in: "$$this.name"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      totalCount: { $first: "$totalCount" }
    }
  },
  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$count", "$totalCount"] } } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$values" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eztjJc8_34i)

Comment: This does not work if there is third document with different values, it find common attributes only for 2 documents

Comment: yes all documents should have same values, then it will be a common attribute